# Are iterators of standard containers DefaultConstructible?

Tags: c++, iterator, initialization

Is this well formed?

```
int main() {
    std::deque< int >::iterator x; // Or any container.
}
```

Bonus questions:

- What about `auto y = x;` which potentially copies uninitialized state?
- What about `… x = {};` which requires a non-explicit default constructor?
- What about `x == y` if both are value-initialized (not default-initialized as illustrated)?

Comment: To answer the bonus questions: 1. `y = x` is only OK if they are value-initialized because default-initialized objects may contain uninitialized members; also see clause referenced from answer to #3; 2. `= {}` is not guaranteed because it is not covered by DefaultConstructible, and I will file a defect report against the C++ standard; 3. see comment on Rapptz's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends on the Iterator concept you're checking.

If it's a regular `Iterator`, which is just the absolute bare minimum to be called an iterator then the answer is no because it has to only meet the constructibility requirements of CopyConstructible, CopyAssignable, and Destructible. (§ 24.2.2 / 2)

However most container iterators meet the requirement of a BidirectionalIterator (except `std::forward_list`, which is an anomaly). All BidirectionalIterators in turn also meet the requirement of ForwardIterator, which meets the requirements of InputIterator (quite a mouthful).

The requirements for ForwardIterator explicitly state:

> A class or pointer type X satisﬁes the requirements of a forward
> iterator if
>
> — X satisﬁes the requirements of an input iterator
> (24.2.3),
>
> — X satisﬁes the DefaultConstructible requirements
> (17.6.3.1),

§ 24.2.5 / 1 in N3376

So yes, this is a valid assumption.

You can find the iterator requirements in § 24.2 but they're nicely summarised in [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept)

Comment: Ah. That clause also says "However, value-initialized iterators may be compared and shall compare equal to other value-initialized iterators of the same type." Super!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they are, however it is not as obvious as it first seems.

If you look at §24.2.2 [iterator.iterators] (n3485), an `Iterator` (in general) is not required to be `DefaultConstructible`. Furthermore, looking at §24.2.3 [input.iterators] and $24.2.4 [output.iterators], neither are `InputIterator` and `OutputIterator`.

Once we get to §24.2.5 [forward.iterators] though:

> 1/ A class or pointer type X satisfies the requirements of a forward iterator if
>
> - X satisfies the requirements of an input iterator (24.2.3),
> - X satisfies the DefaultConstructible requirements (17.6.3.1)
>     [...]

And since all Standard Containers have iterators that satisfy the `ForwardIterator` concept, they all have default constructible iterators.